# Set, Get and Constructors in Java

Tags: java, constructor

Despite Java tutorials, Wikipedia searches, stackoverflow trolling, and hours of reading code samples, constructors still confuse the crap out of me. I've got three related questions that I've been trying to answer to help ME understand constructors a little better.

First, I've been under the impression that constructors need to be named the same as their classes. Consider:

```
public class Money {
    public Money(long l) {
        this.value = l;
    }

    public Money(String s) {
        this.value = toLong(s);
    }

    public long getLong() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return toString(this.value);
    }
}
```

I see this as four constructors...correct? So it *appears* that constructors *not* named the same as the class which contains them allowable. Can someone confirm that?

Second, I seem to have a block against understanding the set and get methods. Consider:

```
 public class GetSetSample {
     public int getFoo()  {
 return int Foo;
 }
 public void setFoo(int fooValue) {
 int Foo = fooValue;
 } 
}
```

Why can't I just do this:

```
public class getFoo(int fooValue){
     foo=fooValue;
}
```

and use `foo = getFoo(12)` from some other class/method?

The third question is a little more esoteric, but will help me conceive of the bigger picture...which is my learning style, and conducive to my ability to trace program flow when debugging. The `get` and `set` methods suggest a "to" and "from" relationship to me. e.g., Passing a value "to" a constructor, receiving the result "from" the get method. It seems to me though that the "to" and "from" will change depending on your perspective. I think that any `setMethod` is setting parameters for an object, even though the variable comes FROM another class or method, and the `GetMethod` is `get`ting the resulting object (say, `this.foo`) with the appropriately `set` parameter. No matter where the `get` or `set` is used, in a main method or a standalone class with a single constructor, 'set' is always associated with sending a parameter and `get` is always associated with receiving an object with that parameter. Is that a good understanding? or am I missing a vital part?

Comment: Which language, if any are you coming from?

Comment: @PastryExplosion - I've got a cobol background and am returning to development after about ten years away. So, pretty much the worst place to be for jumping into OO programming. :D

Comment: Personally I think Java is probably the best place to do it.  No memory management like C++, yet the type system is strong enough to force you to write something coherent.  I'd hate to learn OO, or even teach it, on a language with duck-typing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question 1:

> I see this as four constructors...correct?

No, that class has two constructors and two methods. (`getLong` and `getString` are the methods.)

Question 2:

> Why can't I just do this:
>
> ```
> public class getFoo(int fooValue){
>     foo=fooValue;
> }
> ```

Well, that's trying to declare a *class* with parameters, and also you're *setting* a value in a *get* method, which would be extremely weird. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here, but that code is thoroughly invalid.

Question 3:

> The get and set methods suggest a "to" and "from" relationship to me.

Well it's not really a *relationship* IMO. A relationship suggests something longer term than either of these methods. A setter typically changes the state of an object in some way, and a getter typically just returns some aspect of the state of an object. It's not really clear what the rest of your explanation meant, because you're playing somewhat fast and loose with terminology. For example: "`get` is always associated with receiving an object with that parameter" doesn't really make sense to me. Objects don't have parameters, methods/constructors do - and getters can fetch primitive values or references...

I suspect you would benefit from reading the ["Classes" part of the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html), which talks about constructors and methods.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment? (Looks like someone is simply downvoting *all* these answers, without giving any reasons. What fun.)

Answer (score 3):

You've shown 2 constructors, which do need to have the same name as the class.

You've also shown two "getter" methods, which return the value of the class variable in the form requested by the user.  You can also create "setter" methods, which are used to transfer values into class variables.

You use a constructor to create an object of a particular class, and optionally to set some or all of its internal state (that is, its member variables).

You use setters and getters to isolate the class variables from the outside world, so you don't need to allow other code to access them directly.  Why?  Because, before a setter updates a variable, it can verify that the new value is valid, and that the operation doesn't violate any or the rules (the "business logic") that are required for the class to work properly.

So you could add a setter and update the constructor to use it:

```
public Money(long l) {
    setValue(l);
}

public Money(String s) {
    setValue(toLong(s));
}

// Example setter that validates `l` by prohibiting negative values
public Money setValue(long l) {
  if (l < 0) {
    // Warn about negative values
  }
  this.value = l;
  return this;  // Return the current object to allow chaining; see below.
}
```

Note that a setter usually doesn't need to return a value (that is, it can be type `void`), but it's often helpful to return the object itself.  That allows you to write code like this:

```
Money earnings = new Money().setValue(4).setOtherField("foo");
```

This creates an object of type `Money`, sets various attributes, and stores it in the variable `earnings`.  Clearly, this isn't terribly useful for a simple class like this, but it can be very helpful for more complex classes:

```
Paycheck check = new Paycheck("MyCompany")
  .setEmployee("YourName")
  .setSalary(50,000)
  .setPaySchedule(Schedule.BIWEEKLY)
  .setAccountNumber("1234567")
  .setDefaultTaxRate();
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the first answer, there's only 2 constructors. The difference is on how they are going to be called (called using a string will use the construction having a string has a parameter and called using a long will use the other one). So to answer, yes a constructor has the same name as the class.

The two constructors :

```
public Money(long l) {
        this.value = l;
    }

    public Money(String s) {
        this.value = toLong(s);
    }
```

Regarding the second answer, getters ans setters are not meant to be classes. They are supposed to be within the class itself.

Consider this example which uses getter and setters to get ans set value for the printer class :

```
public class Printer {

    @Inject @Informal Greeting greeting;

    private String name;
    private String salutation;

    public void createSalutation() {
        this.salutation = greeting.greet(name);
    }

    public String getSalutation() {
        return salutation;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
}
```

A good read of this link could definitly help you out !
[Java oriented-object principles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to try to answer your implied conceptual questions -- you've already got plenty of examples of this and that, so I'm just going to try to explain.  I have no doubt you have heard most of this -- maybe all of this -- before, but am not sure and not sure which parts.

Object-oriented programming centers mostly around objects; an object is an amalgamation of code and data.  You define objects by writing a class, and you create one or more copies of the object defined by that class with the class constructor (called *instantiating* the class).

A parallel in other languages: you can have a data structure of related items and a set of subroutines that operate on that data structure.  Think of a class as a way of collecting the items in that data structure and the subroutines that operate on it into one unit.

After you have invoked a constructor, you have a copy of the data defined in that class and a way to refer to that copy.  By referring to that instance when you invoke a class method, you operate on that copy of the data with the methods defined in that class.

If you were to do this in a non-OO language, you could have a routine that created a copy of the data structure in memory and then only use the methods prescribed for it on that data structure.  You could have a pointer to the copy in memory and pass that pointer as a parameter to every subroutine that operated on it, and in fact that's the way some pre-OO systems were programmed.

A constructor is similar to a method call that returns a value; it involves (or can involve) the execution of statements, and it always returns an object of that class.  There are also differences between a constructor and a method; until the constructor completes, for instance, the object is not fully created and shouldn't have some methods invoked on it.

So I hope that helped; if there are conceptual things you still have questions about, perhaps something in here will help you form a specific question so we can explain things further.

Answer (score 0):

Many people have found that if they have spent years learning languages such as COBOL and FORTRAN then changing to OO programming involves unlearning the old languages. I certainly found this when I first tackled C++ 20 years ago. From your description you are clearly struggling with the concepts and I sympathize.

I don't think there is a simple recipe. Practice at the simple examples and don't be disheartened. Don't be afraid to ask on SO - if the questions are clearly asked you will get a useful answer.

Get a good IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, etc.) which allows you to "look inside" objects with the debugger. Hopefully at some stage things will click!

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 - Basic Java Classes:

There's pretty much only 3 things you're going to find in a Java class

- Field/attribute (Depending on your language of origin)
- Method
- Constructor (Which looks like a special kind of method)

Every class is going to have a class name that shares the name of the file it's located in.  So to expand Money out a bit:

```
Money.java
----------
public class Money {
   // This is a field/attribute
   Long value;

   // This is a constructor
   public Money() {
      this.value = Long(0L);
   }

   // This is a method
   public Long getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   // Another method
   public void makeMoney(Long moreMoney) {
      this.value = this.value + moreMoney;
   }
} // Everything in here is part of the Money class
```

The only distinction between a constructor and a method is that a constructor has no specified return value, which is declared as a type right before the name of a potential method. Constructors do have to be named the same as the class they are contained in, but why is implied in how they are written.

Another way of looking at it is if you remove all of the non-type related Java keywords (public, private etc., but not things like float and int) from the front of the method you're looking at (A list of which you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)), is there anything left in front of the method?

With the Money we have at the moment, it would look like this:

- Money()
- Long getValue()
- void makeMoney()

The constructor is the one that has no type for the return value, because it is implied in the declaration.

Question 2/3 - Get/Set methods:

I'm going to say something potentially controversial, but don't worry about these yet.  Get/Set are essentially patterns for Object Oriented development, and generally good Java style, but they aren't required (Last I checked, Android development actually discourages their use when possible for optimization reasons).  Moreover, not all fields in your objects will be accessible or mutable so writing them isn't mandatory.

If you declare all of your fields as public (Like the 'value' field is implied to be right now), you simple can do this:

```
Money myMoney = new Money(new Long(40L));
System.out.println(myMoney.value) // 40
myMoney.value = new Long(20L);
System.out.println(myMoney.value) // 20
```

Aside from that, the notion of get() and set() are just methods.  There is nothing special about them at all.  The main reason they exist is because for general Object-Oriented programming, you shouldn't have to directly modify the internal workings of an object (This is [the principle of Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)).  Everything you should need to affect state or get something out of it should be handled by a method.

In a pithy one-liner: If you need to know the fields of an object to use it, you designed it incorrectly.

*Big Picture*
So what get() and set() really are is a pair of commonly written methods that happen to affect a field in an object in an extremely simple way (get() is a simple access to a field, set() is assignment to that field).  It's just that other methods you write will happen to do more complicated stuff than that.